# Bash: special characters in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace with sed in some bash script something like:

```
s:44:\"STRING\"
```

To:

```
s:NEWSTRING:\"NEWSTRING2\"
```

I tried many ways with escaping special characters, but I got always error

`sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unterminated`s' command`

or someting like that.

Can you please tell me the correct sed -i (sed -i "s/xxx/xxx/g" file) command for that?

Comment: `sed 's:string:"string2":'` ?

Comment: I dont know what you exactly mean with that. Can you post complete command how to replace s:44:\"STRING\" to s:NEWSTRING:\"NEWSTRING2\" please?

Comment: Oh, your examples are not `sed` commands? It's an actual input? In that case: `sed 's/STRING/NEWSTRING2/; s/44/NEWSTRING/'` ?

Comment: No, they are not commands. First one is complete string that I want to replace with second string. Sorry if I wrote it bad.

Comment: I mean someting like:
sed -i "s/s:44:\"STRING\"/s:NEWSTRING:\"NEWSTRING2\"/g" file
but with correct escaping special characters etc. If you understand now.

Comment: Just use single quotes `sed -i 's/.../.../'`.

Comment: If you mean sed -i 's/s:44:\"STRING\"/s:NEWSTRING:\"NEWSTRING2\"/g' file , that dont work.

Comment: You have to escape the backslashes, \\ instead of \.

Comment: It doesnt work too. Please if you have complete command that replace the first one string with the second, please write me. As I wrote, I tried many ways, I tried to escape characters, but I didnt found out the correct command. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the backslashes properly:

```
sed 's/s:44:\\"STRING\\"/s:NEWSTRING:\\"NEWSTRING2\\"/'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 's:44:\"STRING\"' | sed 's/s:44:\\"STRING\\"/s:NEWSTRING:\\"NEWSTRING2\\"/g'
s:NEWSTRING:\"NEWSTRING2\"
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Now it works how I need.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the final delimiter. In your case it seems to be : therefore, you need to add a final : after your substitution content. It does not matter if you are using modification instruction like g

Comment: They are no commands. There is string I want to replace with second string.